# Given a positive integer, how to find next larger integer that's a product of given prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm trying to write a function to estimate a good FFT size, which boils down to finding a number, $M \geq N$ s.t. $M$ is a product of prime factors (in particular $2,3,5,7,11,13$).  Does anyone know an algorithm for doing this?

Comment: So you want an algorithm that would take, say, 101 as its input and output 104 (since $102 = 2 \times 3 \times 17$ has a large prime factor and 103 is prime)?

Comment: Also see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42243/next-restricted-b-smooth-number-problem for some possibly useful references.

Comment: How large will $N$ be?  This is inelegant, but if you're restricting to small values of $N$ you could just store a list of 13-smooth numbers.

Comment: @MichaelLugo I probably have to support sizes up to something reasonably large, say 2^30 (I've personally done 2^27 point FFTs), so a little wiggle room is good...

Comment: A lookup table would be impractical, then.  That's what I suspected but I figured I'd check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple loop. If we have a partial product, one of the "sofar" numbers, that is already larger than the target $n,$ we can only do worse by multiplying by another one of the primes (by increasing that exponent). All the primes are below 20, so it suffices to consider partial products up to $20n.$

BETTER: on reflection, we may take the tighter bound $2n.$ We know that we may get an answer no worse than that using just a power of $2.$

==========================================

```
  n = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13;
  n *= 17 * 19 * 23 * 29;
  n *= 31 * 37 * 41 * 43 * 47;
  n *= 53 * 59 * 61 * 67 *71;
----------------------------------------
  target  n = 557940830126698960967415390

950551829131524428824142413  =   11^12 13^13   :   0,0,0,0,12,13
804313086188212978235812811  =   11^13 13^12   :   0,0,0,0,13,12
680572611390026366199533917  =   11^14 13^11   :   0,0,0,0,14,11
575869132714637694476528699  =   11^15 13^10   :   0,0,0,0,15,10
570389064953586206121040247  =   7^2 11^23 13   :   0,0,0,2,23,1
564735647321977610130979327  =   7^3 11^4 13^18   :   0,0,0,3,4,18
559361527685078641337745931  =   7^5 11^12 13^9   :   0,0,0,5,12,9
558040721244263815738365185  =   5 7^4 11^10 13^11   :   0,0,1,4,10,11
558024051986000542605257595  =   3^5 5 7^9 11^9 13^6   :   0,5,1,9,9,6
558007383225665396344586265  =   3^10 5 7^14 11^8 13   :   0,10,1,14,8,1
557975702410928445496978125  =   3^29 5^5 7^2 11 13^6   :   0,29,5,2,1,6
557959035094845525129909375  =   3^34 5^5 7^7 13   :   0,34,5,7,0,1
557947432080954688960687500  =   2^2 3^14 5^6 7^4 11^5 13^6   :   2,14,6,4,5,6
557941472774676767041705440  =   2^5 3^4 5 7^23 11^2 13   :   5,4,1,23,2,1
557941063680000000000000000  =   2^31 3^5 5^16 7^2 11 13   :   31,5,16,2,1,1

557940830126698960967415390  is target n
```

====================================

==============================================================

```
  n = 1024 * 1024;
  n *= 1024;

  n += 153;
----------------------------------------------------
  target  n = 1073741977

10604499373  =   13^9   :   0,0,0,0,0,9
8973037931  =   11 13^8   :   0,0,0,0,1,8
7592570557  =   11^2 13^7   :   0,0,0,0,2,7
6424482779  =   11^3 13^6   :   0,0,0,0,3,6
5436100813  =   11^4 13^5   :   0,0,0,0,4,5
4599777611  =   11^5 13^4   :   0,0,0,0,5,4
3892119517  =   11^6 13^3   :   0,0,0,0,6,3
3293331899  =   11^7 13^2   :   0,0,0,0,7,2
2786665453  =   11^8 13   :   0,0,0,0,8,1
2357947691  =   11^9   :   0,0,0,0,9,0
2095756663  =   7 11^6 13^2   :   0,0,0,1,6,2
1773332561  =   7 11^7 13   :   0,0,0,1,7,1
1500512167  =   7 11^8   :   0,0,0,1,8,0
1333663331  =   7^2 11^5 13^2   :   0,0,0,2,5,2
1128484357  =   7^2 11^6 13   :   0,0,0,2,6,1
1096135733  =   7^7 11^3   :   0,0,0,7,3,0
1093547455  =   5 7^6 11 13^2   :   0,0,1,6,1,2
1091179089  =   3^2 7^2 11^4 13^2   :   0,2,0,2,4,2
1088602515  =   3^2 5 7 11^2 13^4   :   0,2,1,1,2,4
1086032025  =   3^2 5^2 13^6   :   0,2,2,0,0,6
1084620537  =   3^5 7^4 11 13^2   :   0,5,0,4,1,2
1083647565  =   3^9 5 7 11^2 13   :   0,9,1,1,2,1
1081088775  =   3^9 5^2 13^3   :   0,9,2,0,0,3
1076168025  =   3^16 5^2   :   0,16,2,0,0,0
1074218750  =   2 5^11 11   :   1,0,11,0,1,0
1073765616  =   2^4 3 7^5 11^3   :   4,1,0,5,3,0

1073741977  is target n
```

==============================================================

```
int main()
{

  mpz_class n;
  n = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13;
  n *= 17 * 19 * 23 * 29;
  n *= 31 * 37 * 41 * 43 * 47;

  cout << endl << "  target  n = "  << n << endl << endl;

  mpz_class best = n * n;

  mpz_class sofar2 = 1;

  for(int a = 0; sofar2 <= n * 2; ++a) 
  {
    mpz_class sofar3 = sofar2;
    for(int b =0;  sofar3 <= n * 2; ++b)
    {
       mpz_class sofar5 = sofar3;
    for(int c = 0; sofar5 <= n * 2; ++c) 
    {
      mpz_class sofar7 = sofar5;
      for(int d = 0; sofar7 <= n * 2; ++d) 
      {
        mpz_class sofar11 = sofar7;
        for(int e = 0; sofar11 <= n * 2; ++e) 
        {
          mpz_class sofar13 = sofar11;
          for(int f = 0; sofar13 <= n * 2; ++f) 
          {
                if ( sofar13 < best  && sofar13 >= n)
                {
                  best = sofar13;
                  cout << best << "  =  " << mp_Factored(best) << "   :   " <<  a << ","  << b << ","  << c << ","  << d << ","  << e << ","  << f <<    endl;
                }  // if

               sofar13 *= 13;
          } // 13
          sofar11 *= 11;
        } // 11
        sofar7 *= 7;
      } // 7
      sofar5 *= 5;
    } // 5
       sofar3 *= 3;
    } // 3
    sofar2 *= 2;
  } // 2

    cout << endl   << n  <<  "  is target n  " << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

==============================================================

```
     n = 1024 * 1024;
      n *= 1024;
        n *= 1024;
      n -= 1;
    --------------------
  target  n = 1099511627775

1792160394037  =   13^11   :   0,0,0,0,0,11
1516443410339  =   11 13^10   :   0,0,0,0,1,10
1283144424133  =   11^2 13^9   :   0,0,0,0,2,9
1270933805449  =   7^2 11^10   :   0,0,0,2,10,0
1129612841357  =   7^3 11^7 13^2   :   0,0,0,3,7,2
1126945514695  =   5 7^2 11^5 13^4   :   0,0,1,2,5,4
1124284486325  =   5^2 7 11^3 13^6   :   0,0,2,1,3,6
1121629741375  =   5^3 11 13^8   :   0,0,3,0,1,8
1108332850625  =   5^4 7 11^7 13   :   0,0,4,1,7,1
1105715771875  =   5^5 11^5 13^3   :   0,0,5,0,5,3
1102876442745  =   3 5 7^3 11^8   :   0,1,1,3,8,0
1100272248075  =   3 5^2 7^2 11^6 13^2   :   0,1,2,2,6,2
1099805224518  =   2 3^6 7^4 11 13^4   :   1,6,0,4,1,4
1099598500000  =   2^5 5^6 7 11 13^4   :   5,0,6,1,1,4
1099535990784  =   2^14 3 7^5 11^3   :   14,1,0,5,3,0
1099511627776  =   2^40   :   40,0,0,0,0,0

1099511627775  is target n
```

===========================================================

Comment: Am I right that this is equivalent to trying all combinations of powers and finding the best?

Comment: This actually works pretty well, guess it makes sense that log_13(N) grows pretty slowly in general, I tweaked it and made a recursive version that fits my needs, and lets you easily tweak the factors list, I posted it here: https://pastebin.com/iBp6tXvh  thanks!